# Using approval for customize screen in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I added many custom screens to my Acumatica project and I want to add approval on these, so I found and followed this guide:

[How to work with Assignment and Approval Maps in Acumatica via Automation Steps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400353/how-to-work-with-assignment-and-approval-maps-in-acumatica-via-automation-steps)

And this is my code:
My DAC:

```
[PXEMailSource]
[PXPrimaryGraph(typeof(ProductMaint))]
[Serializable]
public class PSSAProduct : IBqlTable, IAssign
{
    #region ProductID
    [PXDBIdentity(IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Product ID")]
    public virtual int? ProductID { get; set; }
    public abstract class productID : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region ProductCD
    [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Product ID")]
    public virtual string ProductCD { get; set; }
    public abstract class productCD : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region ProductName
    [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Product Name")]
    public virtual string ProductName { get; set; }
    public abstract class productName : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region Active
    [PXDBBool()]
    [PXDefault(true, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Active")]
    public virtual bool? Active { get; set; }
    public abstract class active : IBqlField { }
    #endregion    

    #region OwnerID
    public abstract class ownerID : IBqlField { }
    [PXDBGuid()]
    [PX.TM.PXOwnerSelector()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Owner")]
    public virtual Guid? OwnerID { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region WorkgroupID
    public abstract class workgroupID : IBqlField { }
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<EPCompanyTree.workGroupID>), SubstituteKey = typeof(EPCompanyTree.description))]
    [PX.TM.PXCompanyTreeSelector]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Workgroup", Enabled = false)]
    public virtual int? WorkgroupID { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Hold
    [PXDBBool()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Hold", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
    [PXDefault(true)]
    //[PXNoUpdate] <- Saw this in the PO code, but had to remove so user could save stat of the Hold checkbox
    public virtual bool? Hold { get; set; }
    public abstract class hold : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region Approved
    public abstract class approved : IBqlField { }
    [PXDBBool]
    [PXDefault(false, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Approved", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible, Enabled = false)]
    public virtual bool? Approved { get; set; }
    #endregion


    #region Rejected
    public abstract class rejected : IBqlField { }
    [PXBool]
    [PXDefault(false, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    public bool? Rejected { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Status
    [PXDBString(1)]
    [PXDefault(PSSAProduct.Statuses.Hold)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Status", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, Enabled = false)]
    [Statuses.List]
    public virtual string Status { get; set; }
    public abstract class status : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
}
```

My graph:

```
public class ProductMaint : PXGraph<ProductMaint, PSSAProduct>
{
    public PXSelect<PSSAProduct> PSSAProductView;

    public PXSelect<PSSASetupApproval> SetupApproval;

    public EPApprovalAutomation<PSSAProduct, PSSAProduct.approved, PSSAProduct.rejected, PSSAProduct.hold, PSSASetupApproval> Approval;
}
```

My setup class:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class PSSASetup : IBqlTable
    {
        #region SARequestApproval
        [EPRequireApproval]
        [PXDefault(false, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Null)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "SARequest Approval")]
        public virtual bool? SARequestApproval { get; set; }
        public abstract class sARequestApproval : IBqlField { }
        #endregion
    }
```

And my setup apprval class:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class PSSASetupApproval : IBqlTable, IAssignedMap
    {
        #region ApprovalID
        [PXDBIdentity(IsKey = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Approval ID")]
        public virtual int? ApprovalID { get; set; }
        public abstract class approvalID : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region AssignmentMapID
        [PXDefault()]
        [PXDBInt()]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search<EPAssignmentMap.assignmentMapID, Where<EPAssignmentMap.entityType, Equal<AssignmentMapType.AssignmentMapTypeProduct>>>),
              DescriptionField = typeof(EPAssignmentMap.name))]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Assignment Map ID")]
        public virtual int? AssignmentMapID { get; set; }
        public abstract class assignmentMapID : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region AssignmentNotificationID
        [PXDBInt()]
        [PXSelector(typeof(PX.SM.Notification.notificationID), SubstituteKey = typeof(PX.SM.Notification.name))]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Pending Approval Notification")]
        public virtual int? AssignmentNotificationID { get; set; }
        public abstract class assignmentNotificationID : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region IsActive
        [PXDBBool()]
        [PXDefault(typeof(Search<PSSASetup.sARequestApproval>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Is Active")]
        public virtual bool? IsActive { get; set; }
        public abstract class isActive : IBqlField { }
        #endregion
    }

    public static class AssignmentMapType
    {
        public class AssignmentMapTypeProduct : Constant<string>
        {
            public AssignmentMapTypeProduct() : base(typeof(PSSAProduct).FullName) { }
        }
    }
```

My problem is if I put Acumatica's DAC as SourceAssign of EPApprovalAutomation, it has no error. But if I use my DAC, it throws "Value cannot be null" inside the framework's code.

I checked carefully what the difference between two DACs but I don't realize anything.

My version Acumatica is 17R2.

If you know, please tell me what am I missing.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to check the different between two class and then I found the answer: I missed NoteID field

```
    #region NoteID
    public abstract class noteID : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected Guid? _NoteID;
    [PXNote(new Type[0], ShowInReferenceSelector = true)]
    public virtual Guid? NoteID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._NoteID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._NoteID = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 1):

Normaly, this error "Value cannot be null" is related either to table being defined in the DB with NOT NULL fields or to a DAC with a PXDefault attribute that is empty while trying to persist to DB.

If you used the example in your link and you created your DB table with the audit fields:

```
CreatedByID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
CreatedByScreenID char(8) NOT NULL,
CreatedDateTime datetime NOT NULL,
LastModifiedByID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
LastModifiedByScreenID char(8) NOT NULL,
LastModifiedDateTime datetime NOT NULL,
Tstamp timestamp NULL,
```

make sure you add them to your DAC as well:

```
#region tstamp
public abstract class Tstamp : IBqlField { }
[PXDBTimestamp()]
public virtual byte[] tstamp { get; set; }     
#endregion

#region CreatedByID
public abstract class createdByID : IBqlField { }
[PXDBCreatedByID()]
public virtual Guid? CreatedByID { get; set; }     
#endregion

#region CreatedByScreenID
public abstract class createdByScreenID : IBqlField { }
[PXDBCreatedByScreenID()]
public virtual string CreatedByScreenID { get; set; }          
#endregion

#region CreatedDateTime
public abstract class createdDateTime : IBqlField { }
[PXDBCreatedDateTime()]
public virtual DateTime? CreatedDateTime { get; set; }         
#endregion

#region LastModifiedByID
public abstract class lastModifiedByID : IBqlField { }
[PXDBLastModifiedByID()]
public virtual Guid? LastModifiedByID { get; set; }        
#endregion

#region LastModifiedByScreenID
public abstract class lastModifiedByScreenID : IBqlField { }
[PXDBLastModifiedByScreenID()]
public virtual string LastModifiedByScreenID { get; set; }         
#endregion

#region LastModifiedDateTime
public abstract class lastModifiedDateTime : IBqlField { }
[PXDBLastModifiedDateTime()]
public virtual DateTime? LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }        
#endregion
```

Also check in your code these two possible candidates for PXDefault:

1. In the Status field of the `PSSAProduct` DAC you use `[PXDefault(PSSAProduct.Statuses.Hold)]`. Check you have defined PSSAProduct.Statuses correctly.
2. In the AssignmentMapID field of the `PSSASetupApproval` DAC, the PXSelector `[PXSelector(typeof(Search<EPAssignmentMap.assignmentMapID, Where<EPAssignmentMap.entityType, Equal<AssignmentMapType.AssignmentMapTypeProduct>>>), DescriptionField = typeof(EPAssignmentMap.name))]` could not be finding any records. You could test with a view to make sure it is working.

Comment: the selector of AssignmentMapID haven't had any records because I can't create approval map. It throws "An error occurred during processing of the field GraphType : Value cannot be null.. " error when I select Entity type field (on EP205015). I am sure that 7 default fields work well because I create DAC by generating members of database (a feature developed by Acumatica) and Statuses.List copied from POOrder